# How to show an inverted line in reactjs charts 2?

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs

Is there a way to show inverted line graphs in reactjs-charts-2 ?

For example, we are tracking number of complaints per month.

The more complaints there are, the lower we want the graph to go, with 0 complaints being at the top of the graph.

So the Y scaling should be reversed:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

and so on...

The only way I know to do it currently is to multiply all values by -1. But then the Y axis values show the negative number. Not pretty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. You need to add this to the options object:

```
scales: {
    yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                 reverse: true
           }
    }]
}
```